# Probability measure domain

Tags: probability, measure-theory

On a measurable space $(\Omega, F)$, where $\Omega$ is a set of outcomes and $F$ is a $\sigma -$field, what exactly is the domain of a probability measure $P$?  If it's a specific $\sigma -$field such as $F$, then how can we define the independence on sets from multiple spaces?  And it can't be the whole power set because we can construct sets that have no probability.  I thought the whole point of using a $\sigma -$field was to make the domain of probability measures better to define.

Edit:

So in the textbook $Probability: \ Theory \ and \ Examples$, by Rick Durrett, he says "... $\sigma -$fields $\mathcal{F}_1, \ldots , \mathcal{F}_n$ are independent if whenever $A_i \in \mathcal{F}_i$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$, we have $$P(\cap_{i=1}^{n} A_i)= \prod_{i=1}^n P(A_i)$$..."

How can $P$ be defined on all these $\sigma-$fields?  I thought a probability measure was always w/respect to a given $\sigma-$field.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the question about independence and other probability spaces: what does the domain of $P$ have to do with that?  Clarify a bit more? Give an example?

Comment: Apologies, I'll edit my question

Comment: Ok I edited my question

Comment: @JasonM the sigma fields $\mathscr{F}_i$ are contained in $\mathscr{F}$ (so $\mathscr{F}$ is at least as large as $\sigma(\cup \mathscr{F}_i)$).

Comment: Without more context (I don't have the book) it also seems confusing to me. One should expect that $P$ is defined on the $\sigma$-field generated by all $\mathcal{F}_i$.

Comment: One usually talks about independent *events* (i.e. $A_i \in \mathcal{F}$).

Comment: [Here](https://math.rice.edu/~aib1/425midterm1.pdf) they talk about $\sigma$-fields that are independent that are already subfields of the Lebesgue (or Borel) $\sigma$-field. That at least ensures it's all well-defined.

Answer (score 3):

The domain of $P$ is definitely $F$, the $\sigma$-field on $\Omega$ (it is in some cases the power set of $\Omega$, e.g. for discrete measures on at most countable $\Omega$).

$P$ a function from $F$ to $[0,1]$ obeying certain axioms.  I don't see a relation to independence.

Comment: Yes this was my understanding.  I hope my edit clarifies my question

Comment: The relation is that the sigma fields $\mathscr{F}_i$ are subset of $\mathscr{F},$ (otherwise the independence is a nonsensical issue).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Will M. it appears the most sensible $\sigma-$field for $P$ to be defined on is a $\sigma-$field containing $\sigma(\cup_{i=1}^n \mathcal{F}_i)$.  Without the experience, I had difficulty seeing this, so thanks to everyone who commented.